# Why should I use caching in my code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching

I am researching on the Caching Application Enterprise Library, which is deprecated by  System.Runtime.Caching classes. For this caching concept, why should I use these caching frameworks instead of just using some global objects in my program that can save the objects in my software's lifetime, and these objects can be saved in database or file system if wanted. What's the benefit of using it? Is it only because of thread safe purpose or when should I use it instead of my own global objects?

Can somebody give me a real life good scenario that I should incorporate this caching mechanism in the project (e.g., multi-threading).

Thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useful part of the caching libraries is that they can automatically remove items from the cache after some condition is met (usually after a period of time).

A good reason to start using caching in your project is to increase performance... If you have a website that needs to query the database for each page load, you can cache the database results so that your page doesn't need to hit the database each time.  This can dramatically increase page load times and can allow your site to serve many more users.

When you use caching you are trading real time data for an increase in performance.  Knowing when to expire your cached items so that you prevent the use of stale data is one of the "[two hard things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)".

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a broad question, but here is why you might want to use a System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache instead of a global object:

- You have control over the amount of memory that will be used by MemoryCache.
- A MemoryCache is thread-safe. You need to be careful with this though because though access to the cache itself is thread-safe, it doesn't mean that the items IN the cache are thread-safe.
- Each item you put into the cache can have its own expiration or eviction policy, and you can hook into events that fire when items are removed from the cache.
- There are built-in performance counters that let you monitor the performance of MemoryCache.